# Is it possible to compare two binary trees in less than O(n log n) time?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree

I wrote a java routine to compare 2 binary trees.  I am looking for better algorithms that run in less time.

```
 public class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;
  TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 }

 class Solution {
  public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {

    if  ( p == null && q==null)
        return true;

    if (p == null || q == null) 
        return false;

    if ( (p.val == q.val) && isSameTree(p.left, q.left) && 
      isSameTree(p.right, q.right))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;  
   }   
  }
```

My code takes O(n log n) time.

How to approach reducing the time required?

Comment: If you happen to have a `size` variable at the base of the structure, compare that first.

Comment: Don't write, never present uncommented code. Never code `if (condition) return true;
    else 
        return false;`. Just `// same tree if same root, left, and right return p == q || null != p && null != q
    && p.val == q.val
    && isSameTree(p.left, q.left)
    && isSameTree(p.right, q.right);`

Comment: What do you count as `n`? Your algorithm looks very much linear on the number of nodes.

Answer (score 17):

The current runtime of your approach is actually **`O(n)`**, where `n` should be the *number of nodes of the tree with lesser(or if they're equal) nodes*.

Also, note to compare all the values of a data structure *you would have to visit all of them* and that is the runtime you could achieve and not reduce further. In the current case, at the worst, you would have to visit all the nodes of the smaller tree and hence `O(n)`.

Hence any other approach though might help you with conditional optimization, your current solution has an optimal runtime which cannot be reduced further.

Comment: In fact ... it is O(n) **worst case**.  The best case is O(1).

Comment: @StephenC big-O notation implies "worst case".

Comment: It doesn't always.  For example, we don't say that a `HashMap` insertion is `O(N)`!  By convention, big O refers to the "average" or "typical" case if you don't qualify it.  The problem is that for the OP's example, it is difficult to say what the average is.  That is why it is **a good idea** to be explicit, rather than relying on some vague convention to interpret what we mean,

Comment: Strictly speaking, big O means "upper bound".  You can talk about upper and lower bounds of the worst case (for some algorithms, different ranges of n can have different worst cases) or of the best, average, etc., cases.

Comment: Colloquially we use "worst case O(n)" to mean "upper bound of the worst case" and "average case O(n)" to mean "tight (theta) bound of the average case" since those are the most useful metrics.